# How does it know? When UIColor sets fill and UIGraphicsImageRendererContext knows how to fill

Tags: ios, uicolor, cgcontext, uigraphicscontext, uigraphicsimagerenderer

I came across an example for using `UIGraphicsImageRender` to draw in a tutor on Medium. The example code is as follows:

```
let renderer = UIGraphicsImageRenderer(size: CGSize(width: 20, height: 20))
let img = renderer.image { (ctx) in
    let size = renderer.format.bounds.size
    UIColor.red.setFill()
    ctx.fill(CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: size.width, height: size.height))
}
```

In the above code, `UIColor.red.setFill()` apparently only makes the specified colour, i.e. red, ready to fill up a certain shape. However, magically, the ctx, which is a `UIGraphicsImageRendererContext`, seems to have received a notification that it will fill up the `CGRect` shape with the red colour!

Purely from the code here, I cannot see the connection between the `UIColor` instance method `setFill()` and the `UIGraphicsImageRendererContext` instance method `fill(_: CGRect)`. So, how does it know? How does `UIGraphicsImageRendererContext` fills when `UIColor` sets fill?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Purely from the code here, I cannot see the connection between the UIColor instance method setFill() and the UIGraphicsImageRendererContext

It knows because you are *in* the graphics context when you say `setFill()`.

At every moment when your code is running, there either is or is not a *current graphics context*. At the time that the `image` closure of a graphics image renderer runs, there is one — the graphics context that will be used to form the image. That is what it *means* to be in the `image` closure.

Therefore this and similar UIColor and UIBezierPath commands that are (implicitly) directed at the current graphics context will succeed if given in this closure. They would also succeed in, say, a UIView `draw(_:)` override, because at that moment the view's own graphics context is current.

Try saying `setFill()` at some *other* time, though, and you will see a message complaining that there is *no* current graphics context.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation, @matt. I'm beginning to gain a rough sense of what's going on in the `image` closure. I suspect that somewhere down in the implementation of the `setFill()` method, the `UIColor.red` colour somehow gets hooked up to the `fill(_: CGRect)` method of a certain graphics context through a kind of registration mechanism. Thus, when the `fill(_: CGRect)` method is called in the `image` closure, it checks to see whether there is a registered colour waiting there for it to use to fill up the shape.

Comment: Well, not exactly. UIColor `setFill` is a convenience method for CGContext `setFillColor`.